# V-Collide Collision detect VRML

Tags: collision-detection, vrml

I want to detect collision between VRML object do not want them to draw over each other.
I am my research i find v-collide, but do not know to to use it and can find any website, who can help me. 
Anyone knows how to use it it openvrml so i can detect collision between my objects?